# What does the "-U" option stand for in pip install -U

Tags: python, command-line, pip

Despite a ton of Googling, I can't find any docs for pip's command line options/arguments. What does `pip install -U` mean? Does anyone have a link to a list of pip's options and arguments?

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Type `pip install -h` to list help:

> -U, --upgrade         Upgrade all packages to the newest available version

So, if you already *have* a package installed, it will upgrade the package for you. Without the -U switch it'll tell you the package is already installed and exit.

Each `pip` subcommand has its own help listing. `pip -h` shows you overall help, and `pip [subcommand] -h` gives you help for that sub command, such as `install`.

You can also find the [full reference documentation online](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/); the [*General Options* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/#general-options) covers switches available for every `pip` subcommand, while each subcommand has a separate *Options* section to cover subcommand-specific switches; see the [*`pip install` options* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#options), for example.

Comment: So to upgrade all packages is it no longer neccesary to run something like: `import pip
from subprocess import call

for dist in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    call("pip install --upgrade " + dist.project_name, shell=True)`

Comment: @yourfriendzak: Use `pip freeze --local | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U` to upgrade *all* your packages.

Comment: @user2357112: I actually find the online documentation the be unhelpful in this case, so I don’t think it deserves the prominence you gave it here.