# How do I import scikit-learn in a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I created a fresh conda environment for using scikit-learn and used
`conda install <package>` to install `scikit-learn`, `jupyter`, `pandas`, etc. for compatible dependencies..

I checked if `sklearn` was working after loading the environment:

```
$python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

Since `import` command didn't throw errors, `sklearn` is ready for use. However, I am getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` while trying to import it in a jupyter notebook, that I am running from the same environment.

```
import sklearn
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>()
----> 1 import sklearn

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I was able to import `numpy` and `pandas` in the same notebook without any errors.

Please help me understand the problem and how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Are you sure that `sklearn` is installed in the same environment as you are working in? Check with `!pip freeze` from your jupyter notebook and see if you have `scikit-learn` there.

Comment: Did you `pip install` for `sklearn` in a `conda` environment by any chance? This may cause an improper installation. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html#canopy-and-anaconda-for-all-supported-platforms

Comment: He's using conda and specifically states, the package was installed with conda.  [Managing environments: Conda](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).  `conda env list` will give you a list of your conda environments.  Make sure you activate the correct one with `conda activate myenv` and deactive with `conda deactivate`

Comment: @Trenton_M is right. I have not used `pip install` yet. Also, I have the right environment loaded. I can see `scikit-learn              0.21.2           py37h27c97d8_0` with `conda list`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn)

Comment: I checked the kernel specifications for jupyter notebook and it was using Python3 installed via brew (I am on MacOS). Fixed after I changed it to the conda version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Best practice:** Install everything via conda or pip3, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn).

If that didn't work, check the system paths in jupyter notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

and the system executable:

```
sys.executable
```

These must correspond to the python in your current loaded environment.

For me, the issue was with the jupyter Notebook's kernel. See the kernel specifications in `kernel.json` file in the path. You can find the directory for this file from `jupyter kernelspec list`. I manually changed the python path to the python in my environment (this is a bad idea, but it worked).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your jupyter notebook is finding the same version of python as your terminal, otherwise installing modules with `conda install` in your terminal won't show up in your notebook. Do

`import sys`

`print(sys.version)`

in your notebook and in your terminal. If they do not match up, then add your terminal's python version to your notebook:

`conda install nb_conda_kernels`

`conda install ipykernel`

and then in the notebook switch to the kernel you just installed (kernel -> change kernel)

Answer (score 0):

Check your path for Python and Jupyter:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

You may find different results from Python and Jupyter. This can be fixed temporarily by appending this line of code if you are using macos:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/**your_user_name**/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
```

If you want to solve this permanently, you can create an iPython profile and fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

First activate the finds environment, second launch jupyter notebook, third import sklearn. Inside jupyter notebook.

Comment: Ok. But how? h h h

Answer (score 0):

I have also found the same issue

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

but after searching I found its best solution.

You should also try the following steps:

Step 1:
`open "cmd"`

Step 2:
`write "pip install notebook"`

Step 3:
After installation of notebook, `write "jupyter notebook " in cmd.`

Tell me if you got your solution
thank you!

Comment: The OP was on a Mac. For something not platform specific when installing packages, in a cell in your notebook you can use `%pip install <package>` or `%conda install <package>`. For example, here it'd be `%pip install scikit-learn`. That allows the newer magics commands that insure installation goes to the environment backing the current notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about that. Usually you can leave off the `%` & let automagics handle it; avoid use of `!` from now on for pip/conda.