# How can I fix the Jupiter notebook ModuleNotFoundError for QuantConnect

Tags: python, module, pip, jupyter-notebook, path

I'm trying to import a module in Jupiter notebook but it has the ModuleNotFoundError. Here's what it looks like:

The code I used to find the paths its looking for the modules:

```
import sys
sys.executable
sys.path
```

then it outputs

```
['/Users/username',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/Users/username/.ipython']
```

Then I attempted to install the package with jupyter notebook

```
!pip install QuantConnect
```

and because I installed it before it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: QuantConnect in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.1.0)
```

But I think this matches one of the places that I thought it was searching for the module. I expected it to work but when I try to import it I get the same error.

```
import QuantConnect as Qc

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f774cbf1659e> in <module>
----> 1 import QuantConnect as Qc

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'QuantConnect'
```

I'm using python 3 and I just updated pip to the latest version, nothing I do seems to work.

Comment: See my comment below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71463867/8508004). Try the magics with your package name, **but don't capitalize**. See [here](https://pypi.org/project/quantconnect/) it's lower case.

Comment: @Wayne [pip is case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503509/is-pypi-case-sensitive)

Comment: I learned a couple things looking into this. Thanks @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 1):

The package that you installed is [this](https://pypi.org/project/quantconnect). It is (almost) empty. Looking into your `site-packages`, you should see no `Quantconnect` folder, only a `QuantConnect_Reserved` folder. Also `pip show QuantConnect` shows:

```
Name: quantconnect
Version: 0.1.0
Summary: QuantConnect package reserved for future use
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: QuantConnect Corp.
Author-email: support@quantconnect.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\...\miniconda3\envs\qc\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Note **QuantConnect package reserved for future use**. So the package is only a placeholder so that the name is already reserved by the company