# scikit-learn not importing in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I installed scikit-learn both using pip and conda commandas. Whenever I check the package, it shows that it is already installed but, whenever I try import it, it shows error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
%matplotlib inline
```

ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-82d3fc6531ea> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 import seaborn as sns
----> 5 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I have tried reinstalling it multiple times but it shows the same error

Comment: Please do `pip3 install --upgrade scikit-learn` and post your version of scikit-learn.

Comment: are you using virtualenv?

Comment: I just found out that scikit is not installed with pip3. Whenever I try to install it, the setup shows error and exits with exit status 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn)

Comment: here are some tips and advices: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn/52521214

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that if you install the sklearn package in the python version that you are working. For suppose if your system has two versions of python installed in it like both python 2 and python 3 then you have installed sklearn package in python 2 and executing your code in python 3 or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have latest version of sklearn because in old version of sklearn 
below code was not working.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Please update your sklearn by following command

```
conda update scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while installing these. 
What you can do is install all the packages using the command

```
conda install pandas
```

and all other packages similarly or all in once

```
conda install pandas numpy matplotlib scikit-learn
```

in your project directory.

And now you can open your jupyter notbook using command

```
jupyter notebook
```

in the same environment or I should say same project directory.