# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn' error on Spyder 4.2

Tags: python

I know this has been asked several times in the past, but still can't find the answer...

This is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv")
x = dataset.iloc[:,0:3].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

This is the error

> File "C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Python\Udemy_Machine Learning de A a la
> Z (R y.Python para Data Science)\2.
> Data_preprocessing\Data_preprocessing.py", line 15, in 
> from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

I'm using Spyder 4.2

After trying Carlos suggestion, now the error i get is that Pandas is not found... Is it because i change the interpreter's location?

Comment: Do you actually have sklearn installed?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Did you install Spyder with our installer for Windows or Mac?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn

Comment: I tried installing sklearn using "pip3 install -U scikit-learn" on spyder. Did not work

Comment: Hello Carlos, yes, with spyder's installer for Windows

Comment: Ok, I imagined. Unfortunately, our installers come with a limited set of packages. To use `scikit-learn` you need to download [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) (the Python 3.8 version is fine); then [create an environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) with conda; and finally connect it to Spyder using [these instructions](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment).

Comment: We're very sorry that this process is quite convoluted and hard to do. We'll try to simplify it next year.

Comment: Ok, thank you Carlos. When creating an enviroment, which option should i choose? with a specific version of Python, with a specific package, with a specific version of a package? Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use this command to create your environment: `conda create -n myenv python=3.8 scikit-learn`. That will install Python 3.8 and scikit-learn at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

Try the above comment and install.