# No module named 'sklearn' message on spyder

Tags: installation, scikit-learn, pip, anaconda, spyder

I have been trying everything and still get the error message: No module named 'sklearn' on my spyder

I dnt have that issue with jupyter and it runs fine. any help? thank you

Comment: What exactly have you been trying? Ever thought about creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or is that beyond your capabilities, too?

Comment: @Peter I used the thread in this post and few similar ones. Basically mostly were around updating pip and anaconda that I did all successfully and still get the message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn/52521214

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out I needed to update my Spyder and now the sklearn module is working fine.