# Sklearn installation

Tags: installation, scikit-learn

I have installed sklearn library using
pip install sklearn
but while importing it it shows there is no any library called sklearn that is it gives import error
and afterwars i checked again installing using same command mentioned above but it says requirement already satisfied.
Why it showing like this?
What may be the solution for it? [Here is the problem screenshot while importing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC3S4.png)

It's in CMD

> C:\Users\scann>pip install sklearn
> Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\scann\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.0.post1)

C:\Users\scann>pip install -U sklearn
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in c:\users\scann\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (0.0.post1)

I tried many methods for installation using github and using -U
But also i Didn't find any correct solution

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (2023-01-09), `pip install sklearn` is in a "brownout" period, and installing this way will eventually be removed.

The preferred installation method is:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

The [reason for deprecation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/sklearn-pypi-package) is listed as:

> `sklearn` package on PyPI exists to prevent malicious actors from using the sklearn package, since `sklearn` (the import name) and `scikit-learn` (the project name) are sometimes used interchangeably. `scikit-learn` is the actual package name and should be used with pip.

Further reading:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/sklearn-pypi-package
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24204