# ModuleNotFoundError for 'sklearn' as subdependency of numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using Docker combined with virtualenv to run a project for a client, but getting the error ModuleNotFound for sklearn.

In my Pipfile I have added the numpy dependency

```
numpy = "==1.21.6"
```

The error is thrown from the following line

```
np.load(PATH_TO_NPY_FILE, allow_pickle=True)
```

with the following stack trace:

```
development_1  |   File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 441, in load
development_1  |     pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
development_1  |   File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/code-_Py8Si6I/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 748, in read_array
development_1  |     array = pickle.load(fp, **pickle_kwargs)
development_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

I find this strange, because `sklearn` should be installed as part of the numpy dependency tree, right?

Still I tried the suggestions I found in [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn), like adding the following command explicitly to my Dockerfile

```
python -m pip install scikit-learn scipy matplotlib
```

However, the error still persists.

For completeness, I'll provide some extra info below, although the key question remains why installing numpy does not imply its sub dependencies to be in place.

---

**Project structure**

The project is sort of a bridge between SQS on one hand and the logic of the client on the other. The code from which the error is thrown comes from a git submodule and the Pipfile is added on the top-level repo. The submodule does not contain a Pipfile. The submodules folder has an `__init__.py` file because it contains functions that I want to use in my src code.
In the tree below, my code is in `main.py` and the error throwing code is in `submodules/module2/bar.py`.

```
|- src/
|  |- main.py
|
|- submodules/
|  |- module1
|  |  |- foo.py
|  |  |- setup.py
|  |
|  |- module2
|  |  |- bar.py
|  |
|  |- __init__.py
|
|- .gitmodules
|- Pipfile
|- Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile contents**

Note that at this point, it is a bit of an aggregate of solutions I took from the [other post on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn). That's why both `pip install scikit-learn` and `apt-get install python3-sklearn` are currently included. Will prune later when I finally have fixed this issue.

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR code/

COPY Pipfile .
COPY submodules/ submodules/

RUN pip install pipenv && \
    pipenv install --deploy  && \
    python -m pip install scikit-learn scipy matplotlib && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y locales ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev python3-sklearn && \
    sed -i -e 's/# nl_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8/nl_BE.UTF-8 UTF-8/' /etc/locale.gen && \
    dpkg-reconfigure --frontend=noninteractive locales

ENV LANG nl_BE.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL nl_BE.UTF-8

COPY .env .
COPY src/ .
COPY data/ data

CMD [ "pipenv", "run", "python", "main.py" ]x
```

**Pipfile contents**

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
python-dotenv = "*"
boto3 = "*"
pySqsListener = "*"
xpress = "==9.0.5"
module1 = {path = "./submodules/module1"}
pandas = "==1.3.4"
numpy = "==1.21.6"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I find this strange, because sklearn should be installed as part of the numpy dependency tree, right?

No, `scikit-learn` is *not* a dependency of numpy (it's the other way around).

Since loading that pickle file requires `sklearn`, just put `scikit-learn` in the pipfile (and `matplotlib` if you need it); it's a dependency of your project.

Installing them outside the `pipenv`-generated environment with that `python -m pip install scikit-learn scipy matplotlib` will likely have no effect (nor will the apt-installed `python3-sklearn`), since virtualenvs are designed to be separate from the ambient environment.

Comment: Ah then I must have been wrong about what is depending on what. I based my assumption on the stacktrace raising the ModuleNotFoundError from within the numpy folder. Also second part of your answer seems to make sense, and adding it to Pipfile indeed solves the error. Thanks

Comment: The exception is actually raised within `pickle.load()` (which is called by `numpy.load()`), when the Python built-in deserialization machinery tries to deserialize something that refers to `sklearn`. But yeah, glad I could help!