# No module named 'numba'

Tags: python, conda, numba

I recently installed the numba package using 'conda install numba'. However, when I try to import the library with 'import numba', I encounter an error message stating 'No module named 'numba''.

I've attempted reinstalling the package, but the issue persists. It's puzzling because the program appears in the list of downloaded packages. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or knows how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46113732/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sklearn)

Comment: Sounds like you have two separate installations of python on your computer.  `pip` is using one installation, but you're using a different installation to actually execute the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firsly, double check that you have activated your conda environment **both** before running your code and **also** before installing `numba`

Second: If you are using jupyter notebook, **you need to restart the notebook for the changes to have effect** and for you to be able to import it.

If you already checked that:
You should check that the location the `pip` binaries you are using to install `numba` matches the `python`, `ipython` or `jupyter` you are using to import it.

In other words, if you are using Linux or MacOS, try:
`which pip`
then do one of the three: `which python`, `which ipython` or `which jupyter`
depending on what you are using to run your code.

That will tell you the location of your `pip` and `python` you are using and they should be in the same `/your/path/to/bin` folder.

If they are not: there is your issue. Most likely you will need to `pip install ipython` or `pip install notebook` to resolve this.