# What is the difference between pip install -Ur and pip install -r?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the difference between using `pip install -Ur requirements.txt` vs `pip install -r requirements.txt` I noticed that when using the one with `-Ur` sometimes I get more recent updated packages when compared to using `-r`. I tried to look it up across the internet but didn't find a reasonable explanation. Can anyone please explain the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: `-U` = `--upgrade`: "*Upgrade all packages to the newest available version.  This process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied.*". Your first choice when not knowing what a command line option is doing should be `pip --help`/`man pip`.

Comment: There is no specific "-Ur". Those are 2 _separate_ options, `-U` and `-r`. You see more updates because `-U` gets applied to all the packages listed in requirements.txt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "-U" option stand for in pip install -U](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435209/what-does-the-u-option-stand-for-in-pip-install-u)

Comment: Here's what I got when I use the `-U` by itself: ```$ pip install -U requirements.txt
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: none)
HINT: You are attempting to install a package literally named "requirements.txt" (which cannot exist). Consider using the '-r' flag to install the packages listed in requirements.txt
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requirements.txt```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip's official [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-U) says:

> `-U, --upgrade`
>
> Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. The handling of dependencies depends on the upgrade-strategy used.

So the difference is that `pip install -r` only installs dependencies, while `-Ur` also upgrades dependencies, if there is a new version available.

There's also [another](https://realpython.com/lessons/using-requirement-files/#:%7E:text=A%20Beginner%27s%20Guide%20to%20Pip&text=A%20requirements%20file%20is%20a,current%20projects%20dependencies%20to%20stdout%20.) reference that says:

> Once you’ve got your requirements file, you can head over to a different computer or new virtual environment and run the following:
>
> `pip install -r requirements.txt`
>
> [...]
> This tells pip to install the specific versions of all the dependencies listed.

> To upgrade your installed packages, run the following:
>
> `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt`